# Enforce integrity in Postgresql when data is one join away

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, constraints, integrity

I am working on a db that receives data from users, regarding public transportation. The user can send many info, but what matters for enforcing integrity inside the db is:

- The kind of vehicle (Subway, Bus)
- The number of vehicle
- The (bus/subway) stop where the user is sending data

So far I am enforcing integrity in the server, but the performance is not very good and I would like this to happen in the db itself.
I want to implement a mechanism that checks, whenever a user send some info, if the provided data exists in the db and is correct: for example, I want to check if she provided an existing vehicle, with the correct type, and the correct stop.

The thing is, a vehicle can be of 2 types (bus or subway), and it can have a number. For every vehicle, there is a list of stops.

So I thought that the list of vehicles should be a table on its own, **Vehicles**.
The list of stops lives inside another table, **Stops**.

Each vehicle has an array of integers that refer to the primary keys of Stops.

I've struggled to find a working solution for this. Some say to implement foreign key constraints, but I really don't know how to do this.
Some other say to implement triggers.
How should I proceed? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

How about three tables? You have vehicles, stops and the fact that a particular vehicles visits a particular stop.

```
BEGIN;

CREATE TABLE vehicles (
    vtype char, 
    vnum  int,
    PRIMARY KEY (vtype, vnum)
);

CREATE TABLE stops (
    vtype    char, 
    stopnum  int, 
    location text,
    PRIMARY KEY (vtype, stopnum)
);

CREATE TABLE vehicle_stops (
    vtype   char,
    vnum    int NOT NULL,
    stopnum int NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT valid_vehicle FOREIGN KEY (vtype, vnum) REFERENCES vehicles,
    CONSTRAINT valid_stop    FOREIGN KEY (vtype, stopnum) REFERENCES stops,
    PRIMARY KEY (vtype,vnum,stopnum)
);

INSERT INTO vehicles VALUES
    ('B', 453),
    ('S', 111);

INSERT INTO stops VALUES
    ('B', 1001, 'Trafalgar Square'),
    ('B', 1002, 'Marylebone'),
    ('S', 2001, 'Charing Cross'),
    ('S', 2002, 'Embankment');

INSERT INTO vehicle_stops VALUES
    ('B', 453, 1001),
    ('B', 453, 1002),
    ('S', 111, 2001),
    ('S', 111, 2002);

INSERT INTO vehicle_stops VALUES ('B', 111, 2001);

ROLLBACK;
```

There we go - the 453 bus goes to Trafalgar Square and Marylebone, and the 111 subway train (or underground train as we call them in London) goes to Charing Cross and Embankment.

The foreign keys on vehicle_stops will prevent you entering a bad vehicle/stop combination (like in the last insert).

Comment: This way, I could use vehicle_stops constraints inside the table where I store user-sent data! Is it possible to add a foreign key inside stops, so we refer to the vehicles inside the vehicles table, along with the possibility to add "ON UPDATE" and "ON DELETE"?

Comment: No, `stops` shouldn't refer to `vehicles`, that is `vehicle_stops` whole purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Using foreign key constraints will be a reasonable approach.
(While using triggers could achieve a similar effsct, it is a clear abuse of that mechanism.)

For getting god performance, hoever, it is important to have a reaonable schema in the first place.

You only need to care about vehicle type with your data if you will have a bus and a subway having the same number (bus-4 and subway-4 both exist).  Then having the type in your *vehicles* table keyed by the vehicle number would be sufficient. (vehicle number would imply the type already.)

If number clashes are possible you need to have both keys.

I would assume that there are stops where there are different vehicles stopping at. Then having a match table that relates vehicles and stops (from *stops* table) would be a reasonable way of reflecting that relation.

The primary key of that match ztale would be a perfect foreign key for your data table as that implies existance of vehicle and stop and ensures the vehicel actualy is stopping at the given stop.

So you would have (pseudo code for illustration):

- data table:
  `foreign key (pk_vehicle_stop_match) REFERENCES vehicle_stop_match(pk)`
- vehicle_stop_match table:
  `foreign key (fk_vehicle) REFERENCES vehicles(pk)`
  `foreign key  (fk_stop) REFERENCES stops(pk)`

In case vehicle types are not unique per vehicle number primary key of vehicle would consist of vehicle number and vehicle type